# What's the translation of "back-seat driver" in French?

Tags: traduction

A back-seat driver [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-seat_driver):

> someone who offers unsolicited advice, directions, or help in a situation where someone else is doing something.

What's the translation of "back-seat driver" in French?

Google Translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: Can you specify the sentence/context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1- De manière imagée, le *Grand dictionnaire terminologique* (GDT, OQLF) propose « **mouche du coche** » en référence à la fable de La Fontaine :

> [...]
> Ainsi certaines gens, faisant les empressés,
> S'introduisent dans les affaires :
> Ils font partout les nécessaires,
> Et, partout importuns, devraient être chassés.
>
> [ [*Le coche et la mouche*](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/cochmou.htm), Jean de La Fontaine. ]

2- On y suggère aussi « [copilote](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8362171/copilote) » avec emploi par [ironie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ironie) « **Je n'ai pas besoin d'un copilote !** » parce que le terme [copilote](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C4162) désigne [aussi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/polys%C3%A9mie) celui ou celle qui, dans un avion etc., est (souvent) assis(e) à l'avant lui/elle aussi (contrairement à l'idée de *back-seat*, même si un *back-seat driver* peut être assis à l'avant par ailleurs) et qui assiste le pilote.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec le terme de copilote. Le copilote a été désigné pour assister le pilote et le partage des responsabilités est clair et reconnu. AMHA, *mouche du coche* est une bien meilleure traduction...

Comment: @SergeBallesta agreed, copilote doesn't have any negative connotation, unlike back-seat driver.

Comment: The key part of "back-seat driver" is that the help is unsolicited, and I too think that it's totally missing from "_copilote_".

Comment: @Blackhole "Je n'ai pas besoin de..." (I don't need a) is that part.  Words don't exist in a vacuum and the morphology is different yet the phrase achieves the same effect.

Comment: ***La mouche du coche*** is an excellent translation. It should be made more prominent in your response.

Answer (score 4):

Je suggère une modification de [calque phraséologique](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23822/les-emprunts-a-langlais/emprunts-idiomatiques/quest-ce-quun-emprunt-idiomatique)  ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si%C3%A8ge%20arri%C3%A8re%2Cbanquette%20arri%C3%A8re%2Cconducteur%2Cchauffeur%2Cjouer%20au%20chauffeur%2Cjouer%20au%20conducteur&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) pour les éléments choisis, avec [*petit*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/petit) comme minoratif et [*jouer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer) pour « simuler » mais transitif indirect comme dans *jouer à l'indispensable*.) :

> *Il/elle aime jouer au petit chauffeur à partir de la banquette
> arrière.*

Answer (score 3):

> *Donneur/donneuse de leçons*.
> *Personne qui donne toujours des conseils au conducteur.* [ contexte automobile ]
> [ [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/back-seat_driver/564164) anglais-français ]

Comment: Attention, il serait préférable de regrouper les réponse à la question.

Comment: On peut certes regretter qu'autant de questions soient rédigées en anglais, mais pourquoi tant de haine ?

Comment: Le fait qu'il n'y ait pas d'équivalent exact d'une expression anglaise (un peu obscure) n'implique pas un supériorité de l'anglais. Il y a des tonnes d'expression française assez difficiles à rendre en anglais.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141926/discussion-between-mastodantirafami-and-xoudo).

Answer (score 3):

*Gérant d'estrade(s)*. [ Québec, familier : directement pour l'amateur de sport qui critique et par extension pour généralement ([Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/estrade#f32f0befeb7bfe10)) ]

Answer (score 2):

Though not exactly equivalent as the temporality is normally not exactly the same,

[inspecteur des travaux finis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/inspecteur_des_travaux_finis):

> (Par plaisanterie) Personne qui se plait à donner son avis ou porter une critique sur ce qui a été fait par une autre personne, sans avoir apporté aucune aide personnelle.

still has the notion of the unsolicited advice on someone else's activity. But strictly speaking the backseat driver does so during that activity, while the *inspecteur des travaux finis* does so afterwards (though in practice it is not necessarily that clear-cut).

Answer (score 1):

*[X] en chambre, de salon.* [ par expression [reliée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-seat_driver#Related_idioms) : stratège, jardinier, voyageur, boursicoteur etc. ; Larousse en ligne anglais-français ([*armchair*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/armchair/563149)) ; [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_chambre) ; Termium ([*armchair quarterback*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=ARMCHAIR%20QUARTERBACK&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) ]

Answer (score 1):

L'emprunt du mot anglais, que ce soit en tant que verbe (« backseater » *[bak.site]* du premier groupe, ou « backseat » invariable) ou en tant que nom (« backseater » *[bak.sitœʁ]*), est [très répandu](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-backseat) dans le milieu du streaming de jeux vidéo, et sera probablement compris en dehors de ce contexte par quelqu'un comprenant le sens premier.

> Ne me *backseatez* pas, ce soir !
> J'ai banni de ma chaîne tous les *backseaters*.

Comment: Jamais entendu parler pour ma part, et la signification ne tombe pas sous le sens (je ne l'avais pas compris avant de lire l'explication)

Comment: Oui, le mot ne sera probablement pas compris par les personnes qui ne sont pas de la communauté du streaming.

Comment: N'hésitez pas à commenter si vous downvotez :-).

Comment: Wiktionnaire documente [_backseat gaming_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/backseat_gaming), donc je vois maintenant ta solution comme une réduction de ça, qui est possiblement compatible avec une norme linguistique différente de la mienne en ce qui a trait à l'emprunt.

Comment: Il y a même une [émission](https://mobile.twitter.com/backseat_fr) en streaming assez connue qui porte ce nom. Je viens juste de comprendre la référence de son titre, merci @Blackhole :)

Comment: C'est un anglicisme et pas une expression francaise.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact direct translation, but in some contexts you could use:

Un **pilote de comptoir**

The *comptoir* refered here is the bar. This expression can be used with other noun than "pilote" and generally means someone talking like/pretending to be a *pilote* (or the other qualification used there) but this is actually just (bar) talk as the person is not actually doing any actual *pilotage*.